# Error while running pstack command on the PID

Tags: debian

I'm trying to run pstack on my C++ process. However, the following error is seen. This is a debian buster based instance. Could someone please let me know what is wrong here?

```
pstack 15

15: /usr/local/bin/TestProcess 10.128.2.196 8001 -1 -1
pstack: Input/output error
failed to read target.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the pstack is no longer maintained. The man pages and the [source code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/pstack) doesn't match.

See [Debian Bug report logs - pstack always fails with "crawl: Input/output error"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950168).

You can use gdb as an alternative.

```bsh
$ sudo gdb
(gdb) attach {pid}
(gdb) thread apply all bt
```